# Getting user IP on log in

Tags: jsp, tomcat, authentication, servlets, jdbc

I currently have a web project set up, with form-based JDBC realm authentication set up on the Apache Tomcat 8.0 server.

I want to store the IP address of the user that logs in into a database, using the HttpServletRequest class.

Where (i.e. after what action) would I add this functionality in my web application?

I am using JSP/Servlet, Tomcat, and MySQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a servlet filter for that. The servlet filter can be used to intercept the incoming HTTP servlet request and do whatever you like to the request or log an entry.

Note that Tomcat also has an access log by default that contains all HTTP requests, their status, IP, and username if any. Here is an example.

```
192.168.0.47 - - [27/Nov/2017:07:18:07 -0600] "GET /example/module?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 200 3122
192.168.0.47 - - [27/Nov/2017:07:18:07 -0600] "POST /otherapp/service HTTP/1.1" 200 251
fe80:0:0:0:fc36:e3bb:5bc4:abce%14 - asm-admin [27/Nov/2017:07:18:08 -0600] "POST /otherapp/HEARTBEAT/?v-uiId=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
fe80:0:0:0:fc36:e3bb:5bc4:abce%14 - asm-admin [27/Nov/2017:07:18:18 -0600] "POST /otherapp/HEARTBEAT/?v-uiId=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
fe80:0:0:0:fc36:e3bb:5bc4:abce%14 - asm-admin [27/Nov/2017:07:18:28 -0600] "POST /otherapp/HEARTBEAT/?v-uiId=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Where would I find this log? Also how would I be able to tell which request is the login request, and how would I use that to post to my database?

Comment: You would know it is a login request because it went to the login page. You would know it is a failed login request because the code would be HTTP 401. You would know authN was successful but the user does not have the right permissions because the code would be 403. This log file is inside TOMCAT_HOME/logs. Have a look here for more info: http://www.techstacks.com/howto/configure-access-logging-in-tomcat.html

Comment: This works, thanks! Currently I'm only getting 0.0.0.0.0.1 from getRemoteAddr, but that's correct for localhost, right?

Comment: Can you also explain **when** Filters are triggered? Right now it seems the code inside it is being run multiple times (not just at startup)

Comment: Filters are run for every http request/response hitting that path

Answer (score 0):

After a successful login, you can get the username and IP-Address from the request and process further. I think, the challenge is, just to grab it right after the login, because tomcats form based login is pretty much transparent.
I solved it by saving the username in the session-object and saving the data only, if the values are not already in the session. Probably you have to take into consideration, that a session might expire.

Comment: What would be the "trigger" to storing that session data?

Comment: This could be if the sessionobject 'user' returns null if not set and the value. Something like:  
if ( session.getAttribute("user.name") == null ) {
   saveEntry();
   session.setAttribute("user.name", request.getRemoteUser()) ;
}